# HTML 5 Filereader Not returning Base64 URL Onloadend

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I am using the following script for reading image data as base64 url.

```
function getBase64(incomingfile) {

var reader = new FileReader;
reader.readAsDataURL(incomingfile);
reader.onloadend = ()=>{
    console.log(reader.result);
}
```

}

This is working fine and printing the result on console. But when I try to apply this below code

```
function getBase64(incomingfile) {

var reader = new FileReader;
reader.readAsDataURL(incomingfile);
reader.onloadend = ()=>{
    return reader.result;
}
```

}

I am not getting the result of this function after calling. What should I do to get return value of Filereader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file The FileReader methods work asynchronously but don't return a Promise so when attempting to retrieve the result immediately after calling a method will not work

try this

```
let logBase64 = "";
function getBase64(incomingfile) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(incomingfile);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
reader.onloadend = () => {
  resolve(reader.result);
};
}).then((result) => {
logBase64 = result;
console.log(logBase64);
 });
 }
```

Comment: yes. your code is right! thanks for your time